# Scrolling selection area in an overflow div

Tags: jquery, html

I have created a div which contains an image whose parent div is made scrollable . But when selecting area for cropping it does not scroll the child div. Can anyone please suggest an solution to this ? *Using imageareaselect.min

```
<div style=" width:500px; height:300px; overflow:auto;">
    <div  style=" width:1024px; height:600px ;" >
        <img  src="abc.jpg" style=" box-shadow:3px 0px 12px rgb(192, 192, 192);" id="thumbnail" alt="Create Thumbnail">
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the jquery used to call the selection function

```
$(function(){
    $('#thumbnail').imgAreaSelect({ aspectRatio: '1:0.8228571428571428', onSelectChange: preview }); 
});
```

the selection area goes out of the div and not in the overflow

Comment: code sample will be useful to understand your issue.

Comment: made the edit. check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `position:absolute;` to the first div and add an `id`

```
<div id="container" style="width:500px; height:300px; overflow:auto;position:absolute;">
    <div  style=" width:1024px; height:600px ;" >
        <img  src="abc.jpg" style=" box-shadow:3px 0px 12px rgb(192, 192, 192);" id="thumbnail" alt="Create Thumbnail">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in the imgAreaSelect options add the `id` of the first div as a `parent`

```
$(function(){
    $('#thumbnail').imgAreaSelect({ aspectRatio: '1:0.8228571428571428', onSelectChange: preview, parent: '#container' }); 
});
```

[See Example in JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/w9j3d/1/)

Hope this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

I changed every instance of `fixed` to `absolute` in `jquery.imgareaselect.min.js` and then it worked perfectly inside the `position:relative` div that has `overflow:auto`.